# Dash icons Not Showing properly in Menu Using Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, icons, favicon, dashicons

The **Mega Menu** plugin works well except when activated it affects But some WordPress Dash icons not showing properly.

I have already installed cache plugins like **Autoptimize** and **WP Rocket** as well.

After clear cache from admin side but don't work till now. Also not giving any error in the Browser console.

**URL:** https://www.socomtactical.net

**Max Mega Menu Plugin:** https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/

**Note:** I can't use Elemetor on my Website.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Please let me know what is actually issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add Dashicons on WordPress frontend, you will need to enqueue them using PHP code in your theme functions.php file:

```
/* Add Dashicons in WordPress Front-end */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_dashicons_front_end' );
function load_dashicons_front_end() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
}
```

Sample :

```
<i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-comments"></i>
```

[Chose icon](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#admin-comments)

Comment: I already add this code in my theme fucntion.php. but didn't work right now.

Comment: You should add icon like this <i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-comments"></i>